# Haskell Pipes and Branching

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

## Problem

I'm attempting to implement a simple web server with Haskell and the Pipes library. I understand now that cyclic or diamond topologies aren't possible with pipes, however I thought that what I am trying to is. My desired topology is thus:

```
                                 -GET--> handleGET >-> packRequest >-> socketWriteD
                                 |
socketReadS >-> parseRequest >-routeRequest
                                 |
                                 -POST-> handlePOST >-> packRequest >-> socketWriteD
```

I have `HTTPRequest RequestLine Headers Message` and `HTTPResponse StatusLine Headers Message` types which are used in the chain. `socketReadS` takes bytes from the socket and forwards them to `parseRequest`, which uses Attoparsec to parse the bytes into an `HTTPRequest` object. I would then like the pipe to branch at least twice and possibly more depending on how many HTTP methods I implement. Each `handle<method>` function should receive `HTTPRequest` objects from upstream and forward `HTTPResponse` objects to `packRequest`, which simply packs up the HTTPResponse objects in a `ByteString` ready to be sent with `socketWriteS`.

The following code typechecks if I let GHC infer the type for `routeRequest'''` (mine seems to be slightly off somehow). However nothing seems to be executing after `parseRequest`. Can anyone help me figure out why?

### Code

I have the following code for `routeRequest` which should handle the branching.

```
routeRequest''' ::
    (Monad m, Proxy p1, Proxy p2, Proxy p3)
    => () -> Consumer p1 HTTPRequest (Pipe p2 HTTPRequest HTTPRequest (Pipe p3 HTTPRequest HTTPRequest m)) r
routeRequest''' () = runIdentityP . hoist (runIdentityP . hoist runIdentityP) $ forever $ do
    httpReq <- request ()
    let method = getMethod httpReq
    let (URI uri) = getURI httpReq
    case method of
      GET -> lift $ respond httpReq
      POST -> lift $ lift $ respond httpReq

routeRequest'' = runProxyK $ routeRequest''' <-< unitU
routeRequest' socket = runProxyK $ raiseK (p4 socket <-< handleGET) <-< routeRequest''
routeRequest socket = (p4 socket <-< handlePOST) <-< (routeRequest' socket)
```

`handleGET` and `handlePOST` are implemented as such:

```
handleGET :: Proxy p => () -> p () HTTPRequest r ByteString IO r
handleGET () = runIdentityP $ do
    httpReq <- request ()
    let (URI uri) = getURI httpReq
    lift $ Prelude.putStrLn "GET"
    respond $ B.append (B.pack "GET ") uri


handlePOST :: Proxy p => () -> p () HTTPRequest r ByteString IO r
handlePOST () = runIdentityP $ do
    httpReq <- request ()
    let (URI uri) = getURI httpReq
    lift $ Prelude.putStrLn "POST"
    respond $ B.append (B.pack "POST ") uri
```

I have the following shorthands for proxies:

```
p1 socket = socketReadS 32 socket
p2 = parseRequestProxy 
p4 socket = socketWriteD socket
```

Finally, I run the whole thing like this:

```
main = serveFork (Host "127.0.0.1") "8080" $
    \(socket, remoteAddr) -> do
        ret <- runProxy $ runEitherK $ p1 socket >-> printD >-> p2 >-> printD  >-> routeRequest socket 
        Prelude.putStrLn $ show ret
```

The type signature of `parseRequestProxy` is this:

```
parseRequestProxy
  :: (Monad m, Proxy p) =>
     ()
     -> Pipe
          (EitherP Control.Proxy.Attoparsec.Types.BadInput p)
          ByteString
          HTTPRequest
          m
          r
```

### Edit

Here's the repository with the source code. Be warned it has not been prettied up so use at your own risk. https://bitbucket.org/Dwilson1234/haskell-web-server/overview

Comment: Dwilson are you planning to share the source code of this http server?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I meant to open up the repository once the semester was over. It's in the question now.

Comment: Thanks to you for sharing! You should add a license. BTW... it looks very readable! Congrats!

Comment: Thanks! If you have any questions you can email me at wilsonhardrock at gmail dot com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was wrong when I originally said you could not handle diamond topologies.  I later discovered a sensible way to do this using an `ArrowChoice`-like interface and included the solution in `pipes-3.2.0` in the form of the `leftD` and `rightD` combinators.  I'll explain how it works:

Instead of nesting proxy transformers, you wrap the result with a `Left` or `Right`

```
routeRequest ::
    (Monad m, Proxy p)
    => () -> Pipe p HTTPRequest (Either HTTPRequest HTTPRequest) m r
routeRequest () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    httpReq <- request ()
    let method = getMethod httpReq
    let (URI uri) = getURI httpReq
    respond $ case method of
      GET  -> Left  httpReq
      POST -> Right httpReq
```

Then you can selectively apply each handler to each branch and then merge the branches:

```
routeRequest >-> leftD handleGET >-> rightD handlePOST >-> mapD (either id id)
    :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => () -> Pipe p HTTPRequest ByteString IO r
```

If you have more than two branches then you will have to nest `Either`s, but that is just a limitation of how `ArrowChoice` works.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but GHC couldn't deduce (r ~ ()) for the version of routeRequest you gave. Not a huge issue, I can specify it in the type manually but I'd rather it be polymorphic. Other than that this is great!

Comment: @Dwilson Actually, that's because I forgot to put a `forever` there.  I'll fix it.

Comment: I have a related question. If I wanted to use `pipes-safe` to read the requested file, how would I go about that? Can `readFileS` be embedded as part of handleGET? Something like `readFileS (docRoot ++ uri) >-> mapD Message` perhaps? I can put this in a new question if that's more appropriate.

Comment: You can do this in the next `pipes` release.  The technical reason is that `leftD` requires a `ListT` instance and I only just recently figured out how to implement `ListT` for all the proxy transformers, including the `EitherP` proxy transformer that `readFileS` uses.  If this feature is urgent then just check out and install `pipes` HEAD from github.  Also, if you have other questions, feel free to e-mail me to ask.  My e-mail address is Gabriel439 at Google's mail service.

Comment: I don't see these in the latest version. What is their replacement?

Comment: @dfeuer These moved to `Pipes.Extras`, which has `left`, `right`, and `(+++)`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez, thanks a lot! Do you think you could link to that from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes ?

Comment: @dfeuer Alright, I will.  Where do you think it should be mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez, the key phrase from my perspective is *in the documentation*, but if I were you, I'd probably stick it in the package description, and perhaps mention the pipes packages by other people that you consider most important, possibly drawn from [the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pipes). `pipes-extras` could use a bit more documentation, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have not run your code, but I think I spotted a problem.

```
routeRequest'' = runProxyK $ routeRequest''' <-< unitU
```

`routeRequest'''` is requesting data from unitU which has nothing to supply, so it hangs.

```
:t runProxy $ unitU >-> printD
```

Will type check but nothing runs.

It seems like the data is being sent to the wrong level of the monad transformer, data which is flowing into `routeRequest` should be flowing into `routeRequest'''`.  The data flowing into the wrong level of the monad transformer is what is probably causing you to need to leave of the type signature to get everything to type check.  With the type signature `routeRequest` is expecting a `()` coming from upstream and, I bet, with no type signature it is allowed to be polymorphic.

In your definition of `routeRequest` you could "close the pipe", I think that is what it is called, by using unitD which would disallow your construction even when `routeRequest'''` does not have the type signature.